# Is certificate holder correct? If not, which word is correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it correct to say that someone is a holder of a university certificate or degree, if they have earned it? If not, what is the correct word?

Comment: to have a degree in x. To have a certificate of or for x.

Comment: *To **have** or **hold** [an academic qualification]* are still [about equally common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=He+has+a+degree%2CHe+holds+a+degree&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=10) But the latter is a bit more "upmarket" and it's gradually becoming relatively ***dated***. And *to **be the holder** of a degree* is just a bit on the "pompous" side. Stick to ***have*** if you want to avoid sounding "quaint" in decades to come.

Answer (score 2):

It is not incorrect to say it, provided you mention what the certificate entitles. Like in your case, an university certificate holder.

However, to address academic issues, it is better to use the term, '[degree holder](https://www.lexico.com/definition/degree_holder)' which can refer either to a Bachelor's degree or a Master's degree.

But there are most sophisticated terms for the same. If a person has completed his/her university studies, he/she is awarded the ***[baccalaureate](https://www.lexico.com/definition/baccalaureate)*** or ***bachelor's degree***. So you can say Bachelor of Technology in Civil or Bachelor of Technology in Information Technology.